# passing iterators to lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, iterator

I want to use the lambda expression for the following codes,

```
long long noOfways =0;
 auto dist =0;
 for(auto iter = noChocolets.begin()+1;iter!=noChocolets.end();iter++)
 {   
     dist+=*(iter)-*(iter-1);
     noOfways+=  minOper(dist);
 }
```

I particularly want to convert  **for loop** to a lambda expression. How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to use a lambda?

Comment: Why do you want to change a working code, that (my opinion) doesn't need refactoring?

Comment: I want to see if there is a way to use lambda for the above code

Comment: Considering that you use iterator arithmetic inside the loop body, it's going to be really hard to replace with a lambda. *Why* do you want to do it? What problem do you think a lambda would solve that your current loop doesn't? And you still can't escape the loop if you want to iterate, there still has to be a loop *somewhere* even if you don't write it explicitly.

Comment: Try a [range-based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) first. No need for a lambda.

Comment: @Ansu - This is an XY Question. You have an issue X and you ask about the (**wrong**) solution you have in mind, Y. So ask about X directly.

Comment: @StoryTeller Kind of hard to use a range-based for if the OP needs the *previous* value (`*(iter - 1)`). The only thing that I can see replace the explicit loop is the two-input-iterator version of `std::transform`, which isn't really correct to use in this case since nothing is "transformed".

Comment: @Ansu By the way you have a possible bug lurking in that `for` loop... What if `noChocolets` is *empty*? Then `noChocolets.begin() + 1` is *undefined!*

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Moving forward to a range based for will require some restructuring of course. Not impossible, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with std::accumulate.

```
 accumulate(noChocolets.begin()+1, noChocolets.end(), noChocolets[0],
    [&](long long left, long long right){
        dist += right-left;
        noOfways += minOper(dist);
        return right;
    });
```

Seems to work, although this is a strange and obscure solution. The original one is much cleaner if you ask me. I would consider this one to be an abuse of the accumulate method and DO NOT RECOMMEND to use it.

[Working example](https://ideone.com/rl3GyA)

Comment: *"abuse of the accumulate"* - I disagree. There's nothing abusive about accumulating differences. And the named algorithm makes it clearer to me over a loop. +1

Comment: I mean accumulate is meant to return the result of accumulation. This one just returns the last element. This way this solution is obscure and abusive to me.

Comment: If the value wasn't discarded I'd agree with you. The algorithm is perhaps more general than is required here, but this is still a nice solution and you won't convince me otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract it just in case you need to reuse it in the **same block**

```
auto f = [](auto& itercollection)
{
    for(auto iter = itercollection.begin()+1;iter!=itercollection.end();iter++)
    {   
        dist+=*(iter)-*(iter-1);
        noOfways+=  minOper(dist);
    } 
}
```

then just call it over:

```
f(noChocolets)
f(noChocolets2)
f(noChocolets3)
```

Comment: I want to replace the for loop with lambda, is it possible?

Comment: @Ansu, if you need to **iterate** you have to iterate, `lambdas` are just anonymous functions.

Comment: Honestly, suggesting for_each over a range-based for and no lambda, is weird

Comment: @StoryTeller, now you say it, yeah, its not correc, im gonna edit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of iterators are equivalent with range-base loop/lambda and `std::for_each` so there is always a way to replace one of the approaches to the other. But as mentioned in comments the iterator approach has advantage of its clearness... Exemplary c++17 solution:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <optional>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4};
    auto dist =0;
    long long noOfways =0;
    auto minOper = [](auto e) {return e;};
    std::optional<decltype(v)::value_type> prev {};
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](auto e)  { 
        if (prev.has_value()) {
            dist += e - prev.value();
            noOfways+=  minOper(dist);
        }
        prev = e;
    });
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/snm5wQQMPlwRVVmj)

To back port it to c++11 use [boost::optional and non-generic lambdas](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vnpz3EmzBPuzd5ro).